# Setting margins in `text-mode`

Tags: text-editing, text-properties, text, margins

I use text files for most of my work. 
But for printing them on letterhead, I need to set margins to say 3 cm for upper margin and 2.5 cm for lower. 
Is there any way I can define them in `text-mode`. Can I make them default for all my docs. 
I don’t want to use LaTex or org-mode for simple few line letters or memos

Comment: Text mode is about plain text. It knows nothing about paper sizes. Your printer settings define default top and bottom margins for pages. If you describe how you print your text documents, someone might be able to help, but it is not an emacs issue.